# Accordion Component in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7, accordion, bootstrap-accordion

I am looking for an accordion to replace mdb-accordion that is being currently used as its a pro component. I have installed Squeezebox( [https://www.npmjs.com/package/squeezebox?activeTab=readme )]but I don't think the script is working.

```
<squeezebox [multiple]="false" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <sb-item class="greyBack">
    <sb-item-head class="dropdownTitle">{{page.fields.accordionTitle1}}</sb-item-head>
    <sb-item-body>
      <div class="dropdownText" [innerHTML]="page.fields.accordionDescription1 | markdownToHtml" spaLinkTransformer></div>
    </sb-item-body>
  </sb-item>
</squeezebox>
```

[image]
Appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any errors? What is not working?

Comment: I don' see any errors on the consoe. updated my post with the screen shot of how it looks

Comment: Looks like you are missing the stylesheet. I would start with re-reading the installation instructions

Comment: Thanks MikeOne. I have  <link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"  href="/node_modules/squeezebox/styles.css"> in index.html. Do you think the browser isnt gettting the stylesheet?

Comment: That explains. The node_modules folder will not be available after build. You need to reference the stylesheet from your angular.json file.

Comment: thanks MikeOne. I will try adding and see.

Comment: Brilliant ! thanks @MikeOne. That worked !!

Comment: Excellent! Glad you’re sorted